# Activating a python virtual environment within a bash script fails with "sudo: source: command not found"

Tags: python, bash, sh, virtualenv

I'm trying to automate the deployment of my Python-Flask app on Ubuntu 18.04 using Bash by going through the motion of preparing all the necessary files/directories and cloning the source code from Github followed by creating the virtual environment, installing the pre-requisite modules and etc.

Now because I have to execute my Bash script using `sudo`, this means that the entire script will be executed as `root` except where I specify otherwise using `sudo -u myuser` and when it comes to activating my virtual environment, I get the following output: `sudo: source: command not found` and my subsequent pip installs are all installed outside of the virtual environment. Excerpts of my code below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
...
sudo -u "$user" python3 -m venv .env
sudo -u $SUDO_USER source /srv/www/www.mydomain.com/.env/bin/activate
sudo -u "$user" pip install wheel
sudo -u "$user" pip install uwsgi
sudo -u "$user" pip install -r requirements.txt
...
```

Now for the life of me, I can't figure out how to activate the virtual environment in the context of the virtual environment if this makes any sense.

I've scoured the web and most of the questions/answers I found revolves around how to activate the virtual environment in a Bash script but not how to activate the virtual environment as a separate user within a Bash script that was executed as `sudo`.

Comment: Do you know what `source` does?

Comment: Anyway even if `source` would work the virtualenv deactivates when `sudo` finishes. The entire script must be run under one `sudo` session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `source` is not an executable file, but a built-in `bash` command. It won't work with `sudo`, since the latter accepts a program name (i.e. executable file) as argument.

P.S. It's not clear why you have to execute the whole script as root. If you need to execute only a number of commands as root (e.g. for starting/stopping a service) and run a remaining majority as a regular user, you can use sudo *only for these commands*. E.g. the following script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# The `whoami` command outputs the current username. Unlike `source`, this is
# a full-fledged executable file, not a built-in command
whoami
sudo whoami
sudo -u postgres whoami
```

on my machine outputs

```
trolley813
root
postgres
```

P.P.S. You probably don't need to activate an environment as `root`.

Comment: The reason I'm running the script as `root` is because some of the commands I'm running in the script requires `sudo` like stopping and starting services unless I'm getting confused about `sudo`.

I failed to mentioned that I've also tried not using `source` and here's the line that I tried:

```Python
sudo -u "$user" . /srv/www/www.domain.com/.env/bin/activate
```
As I understand, the `.` is just an alias for `source`.

Comment: @JeremyTan If you use `sudo` only for the desired commands (running the entire script as regular user), they would still be executed as root (or any user you specify as argument to `sudo`).

Comment: @JeremyTan I've updated the answer, adding an example to it.